# Transition from Green to Red UIColor within a defined pixel range

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uibezierpath, uicolor

I've got this horizontal bar (rectangular area) that represents a voltage from 0 to 5V.  If, for example, the voltage is 2V, the bar fills up to the 2V mark with the color green.

From 0-2.1V, the color of the area representing the voltage should be green.  From 2.9-5V, the color should be red.

I want to make a color transition from 2.1-2.9 that goes from green to red.  I've tried one solution that I got from another StackOverflow topic, but I don't like the results because there are too many colors in the spectrum that don't look like they belong.

Here is that solution (the 80 is for the range 2.90 - 2.10 = .80):

```
- (void)updateLayerProperties {
    CGRect barRect = self.bounds;
    barRect.size.width = (self.bounds.size.width * self.value)/3.5;
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:barRect];
    self.barLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    if (self.value >= 1.30 && self.value <= 1.70) {
        self.barLayer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:((255 * (self.value - 1.00)) / 80)
                                                  green:((255 * (80 - (self.value - 1.00))) / 80)
                                                   blue:0
                                                  alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    } else {
        self.barLayer.fillColor = (self.value >= self.threshold) ? self.fullColor.CGColor : self.emptyColor.CGColor;
    }
    self.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth;
    self.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor.CGColor;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

Originally, I just had 0-2.5V is green, 2.5-5V is red...but this looks bad to eye, so I'm trying this out.

Is there some type of animation to use instead of calculating colors based on value of voltage?  Assuming the transition gap is the 2.1 - 2.9, the transition should know how to display the best colors between Green and Red.  Thanks.

[Bar image, with value > 2.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUvUh.png)

Comment: I'd suggest (based on bar width of 100, for explanation): green layer from 0 -> 21; green-to-red gradient layer from 22 -> 28; red layer from 29 -> 100. Then mask it to the desired width.

Comment: do you know how I'd write that out?  Create a `CAGradientLayer` object? And if so, how would I set the `barLayer.fillColor` with the `CAGradientLayer` object color?  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

---

```
//
//  GradientBarView.h
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/5/18.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GradientBarView : UIView

@end
```

---

```
//
//  GradientBarView.m
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/5/18.
//

#import "GradientBarView.h"

@interface GradientBarView ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) CAGradientLayer *gradLayer;
@end

@implementation GradientBarView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)commonInit {

    // instantiate the gradient layer
    _gradLayer = [CAGradientLayer new];

    // initial size
    _gradLayer.frame = self.bounds;

    // 4 colors, so we can have solid - gradient - solid
    _gradLayer.colors = @[
                          (__bridge id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor,
                          (__bridge id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor,
                          (__bridge id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                          (__bridge id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                          ];

    // 0.0 -> 2.1 should be green
    // 2.1 -> 2.9 should be a green-to-red gradient
    // 2.9 -> 5.0 should be red

    _gradLayer.locations = @[
                             @(0.0),
                             @(2.1 / 5.0),
                             @(2.9 / 5.0),
                             @(1.0)
                             ];

    // make it horizontal
    _gradLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
    _gradLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);

    // add the gradient layer
    [self.layer addSublayer:_gradLayer];

}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    _gradLayer.frame = self.bounds;
}

@end
```

---

```
//
//  GradBarViewController.h
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/5/18.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GradBarViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

---

```
//
//  GradBarViewController.m
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 4/5/18.
//

#import "GradBarViewController.h"
#import "GradientBarView.h"

@interface GradBarViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) GradientBarView *gradBarView;
@end

@implementation GradBarViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // instantiate a GradientBarView
    _gradBarView = [GradientBarView new];

    // we'll use autolayout
    _gradBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // add the view
    [self.view addSubview:_gradBarView];

    // center a 300 x 40 view

    /* center horizontally to superview */
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_gradBarView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.view
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0].active = YES;

    /* center vertically to superview */
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_gradBarView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.view
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:0].active = YES;

    /* Fixed width */
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_gradBarView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:nil
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:300.0].active = YES;
    /* Fixed Height */
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_gradBarView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:nil
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                multiplier:1.0
                                  constant:40.0].active = YES;

}

@end
```

---

Result (click the image to see it full-size):

[image]

I'll leave it up to you to look up how to mask the view so you're only showing X-number of points from the left.

Comment: works like a charm, thank you very much.  I'm working out the code for the mask now.